# what does ''would have seen'' mean,what grammar is it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

This is a text about elderly people. Two persons wear makeup to look like old people and to understand what it's like to be old. after this experiment one of them said this.

> They were talking about real things and I felt unqualified. I didn't
>   have that life experience. They had been through so much. It made me
>   realize how ignorant I was. It was as if I was seeing the young people
>   inside them.Before I **would have just seen** the wrinkles.

I can't understand the meaning and what grammar this is?

Comment: The last sentence would make more sense with a comma in it: "Before, I would have just seen the wrinkles."

Answer (score 3):

An unreal conditional:

If I **had understood** the grammar, I **would have explained** it to you.
First verb: past perfect, Second verb: past conditional.

In your sentence, the first part is assummed, it is not spoken, it would look like this:

[If I **had not done** this experiment of putting on make-up to look like an old person], I **would have just seen** the wrinkles. [and not how they are real people].

Just seen means: only seen old people as people with wrinkles and not as "great" people in their own right.

In English, we often imply the first part of an unreal conditional and do not state it clearly,

Comment: I think OP's *precise* context doesn't actually refer to an "unreal" situation. It's more like *On Friday nights I would go to the pub* - referencing ***habitual action in the past***.

Comment: The OP's question is most definitely UNREAL: If, in the past, I had tried to understand what old people were, I would have [verb: ]. That is the implied grammar here. There is no habitual action in the past. It's an IF situation. It's a one off deal imagined by the speaker. In that sense, it is unreal. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: My recollection is you don't take kindly to people disagreeing with you here, so there's probably not much point in me posting this. But it seems pretty obvious to me that OP's writer ***had*** interacted with older people before realising how ignorant he was, and therefore he ***did*** just see the wrinkles. To all intents and purposes, that final sentence is semantically equivalent to *I just saw the wrinkles before.*

Comment: Thank you. should it have a comma after ''Before''?                        
 ''Before, I would have just seen the wrinkles."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. we use would for habitual action in the past- can we use ''would have'' for that, too?

Comment: @Masih K You (one) cannot explain every single thing with every question. Yes, at times "would [verb]" can be used for that, but not here. There is nothing habitual here at all. Finally, this is not: On Friday nights, I would go to the pub (habitual). Conditional. This is: If it had been a Friday night, I would have gone to the pub. ***Would go***=conditional, ***would have gone***= past conditional. Not the same tense at all. Fumble Fingers' example is in a different tense.

Comment: your answer is clear but now I'm confused about ''would have'' and past tense. I know we use would for habitual action (like ''used to''). but could you please give a sentence when ''would have'' is used instead of past tense and not conditional if there is any?

Comment: @Masih K I have already done that in the previous post using the same ideas. Please reread it. Also, It is not "would have plus past tense". It's called the conditional past tense: would have gone, would have seen, would have walked.